# cookie.maxAge goes back to originalMaxAge value on each request

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, express-session

I'm setting maxAge to 30minutes. after login i didn't make any event in my application. but every five minutes i'm making GET api call to get count of records. After every api call my cookie.maxAge value reset to originalMaxAge, so my application not get session expire.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
app.use(session({ 
    name: 'rootElementId',
    secret: jwt_secretkey,
    store : sessionStorage,
    cookie: {  path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null },
    saveUninitialized : false,
    resave: false,
    rolling: false,
    genid : function(req){
        return "SEC_KEY"
    }
}));
router.use('/getCount', function(req, res){

    var count = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( req.session.mgmtResponse ));
    res.send('{"count":count}');
});
router.use('/getData', function(req, res){
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 60000;
    req.session.touch();
});
```

Note: In Nodejs version 9.8.0 its worked fine. After update Nodejs version 8.11.1 i'm facing this issue.

Comment: what's your `rolling` and `saveUninitialized` config for session config ?

Comment: rolling and saveUninitialized i'm passing false.

Comment: Maybe try with `true` ? and also try to use `expire` instead of `maxAge`